# docker-compose : Issue with .env path

Tags: docker, environment-variables, capistrano

I'm trying to run a dockerized project which is deployed with Capistrano

My application is located within `/opt/hosting/my-project` directory with the following structure :

```
/opt/hosting/my-project
    /current -> releases/201704251234/
    /releases/201704251234/
    /repo/
    revisions.log
    /shared/
```

Currently, what I'm trying to do is simply :

```
cd /opt/hosting/my-project/current
docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml up -d
```

This fails with the following error :

`ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /opt/hosting/my-project/shared/.env`

This is the content of my docker-compose-production.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
    app:
        build: ./
        container_name: myproject_app
        env_file:
            - /opt/hosting/my-project/shared/.env
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes: 
            - /opt/hosting/my-project/:/opt/hosting
```

The .env file needed exists, is readable and doesn't seem to contain any error. Here is its content :

`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myproject`

My docker-compose -v :

`docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387`

Does anyone have an idea on why this is failing ?

Cheers !

Comment: I think that your docker-compose file is not able to se what is beyond your project directory, you need to move your `shared/.env` file inside the folder `current`, otherwise...

Comment: @dzof31 Unfortunately I need to keep the .env file in this directory because application is deployed with Capistrano. The "shared" folder contains all files that should not change throughout various deployments.
I'll try tomorrow to move this file at the same level than the docker-compose file to see if it works this way and if so, i'll change my deployment procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after many tries, I've managed to start my application.

What I've tried to do is :

1. Symlinking my .env files in current directory using Capistrano's feature "Linked files" :
   /current/.env -> ../../shared/.env
   Unfortunately this failed as docker-compose doesn't seem to find files or folders that are not within directory where it is executed.
2. Removing .env linked file from Capistrano config, and manually copying it through a custom Capistrano task.

   ```
   namespace :env_file do
     desc "Copy shared .env file"
     task :copy do
       on roles(:docker) do
         within current_path do
           execute "cp #{shared_path}/.env #{current_path}/.env"
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```

The last solution worked and I'm currently using this one for my deployments. I'll post updates on this issue if I found new problems or improvements.

However, is it normal that docker-compose fails using symlinked .env files ?

Cheers